# jQuery: Need to Use ID Contains *= Selector, Always 1 Element, will individual ops always work?

Tags: jquery

At any given time I always have 1 DOM element with the ID *= STARTTIME, e.g.

```
Element434291_STARTTIME
Element238721_STARTTIME
```

etc.

They get replaced/recreated in the DOM dynamically and at most 1 such element exists, but I don't know its unique ID in Part 1 of this expression.

Throughout the code I use individual operations with `*=` such as

```
$('input[id*=STARTTIME]).val()
$('input[id*=STARTTIME]).html('..')
```

Is this safe, and will `val()` always return exactly 1 element? Normally, if there was a list, I would have to do `$('input[id*=STARTTIME])[0].val()`, but in this case I know there will be no list.

Comment: Given that you said there is only ever one element with the STARTTIME, then that selector will only ever match one element.  Should that rule ever change ...

Comment: But does the *= selector always return a List? Or does it depend on size, List if >1 and Element if ==1?

Comment: It will always return a jQuery object.  Which will contain an inner result stack size of 0-n.

Comment: `val()` as a getter will always only return value of first matching element in selector

Comment: It would also be more appropriate to use the [`$=`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector which stands for `ends-with`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all jQuery methods when used to **get** values...like `html()` , `val()`, `prop()`, `css()`, `attr()` etc only return the value of the first matching element in a collection.

The only exception I know of is `text()` which returns concatenated text of all elements in the collection. Many have wondered why this one method behaves differently than the others

Using `val()` as a getter you will always get value of the first element. Note that none of this is true for setting values. When setting,  the method will be applied to all in a collection

```js
var $inputs = $('[id*=_STARTTIME]');
var value = $inputs.val();

console.log('# of matching elements=', $inputs.length);
console.log('val():' , value)
console.log('value equals first input value:', value=== $('input:first').val())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Element434291_STARTTIME" value="Element434291_STARTTIME">
<input id="Element238721_STARTTIME" value="Element238721_STARTTIME">
```